Custom rules conditions in a process for assigned user
i'm trying to configure Azure Devops Server in a local installation and now i'm trying to configure permissions but i don't find how to do what i need.
I need to configure that an assigned user to a work item can do changes like the state, but a non assigned user can't do that. Now, everybody can modify all or i can set that anybody modify anything, but i need that only the assigned users (or administrators) can modify a work item.
The same with Repos. I need assign users to Repos and users without this assigment can't sent files or updates.
I tryed searching the security project level, security collection level, area level,.... and all is for all items, assigned or not.
Later y see the Process Rules, with conditions an actions, but in conditions i can't indicate Assigned user = [Me] or something like that, only "The current user is member of the group..." or not. With the condition "The value of... (equal)" or "The value of...(not equal)" not let me to choose the "Assigned to" field.


I need that only the assigned users (or administrators) can modify a work item.

Currently, there is no way to make only the assigned users can modify a work item. You can set an administrators group, then set a rule that if the current user is not a member of the administrator group, make the fields read only. Here is the example.

The same with Repos. I need assign users to Repos and users without this assignment can't sent files or updates.

For the repo, there is no way to assign a repo to a user. You can control the user permission of Repositories in the Project Settings > Repositories > Security tap：

As the functions you need does not exist currently, you can also request a feature for Azure DevOps here to help the feature better. Engineers usually prioritize features that are urgent or have more votes.

Ok, thank you so much. I'll request this feature that i need.

Hi @MarcosGarcia, thanks for help the feature better. :)
